Can I call seek on a subprocess stdout pipe and expect it to work in Windows 11?
If I use p = subprocess.Popen(..., stdout=subprocess.PIPE), can I call seek on p.stdout and expect it to work in Windows 11?
From this link (2011), it seems that the expected answer is no, as "you cannot seek on a pipe." That link also shows an IOError occurs when you try.

https://bugs.python.org/issue12877

from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
p = Popen(['ls'], stdout=PIPE)
p.wait()
p.stdout.seek(0)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t.py", line 5, in <module>
    p.stdout.seek(0)
IOError: [Errno 29] Illegal seek

Python 2.7.2, Arch Linux x86-64 (Kernel 3.0)

However, it appears there may be OS-specific things at play or updates to Python since that date which may change the answer as I can get this program to run if I change "ls" to a windows command. Also, the type of p.stdout is a io.BufferedReader, the call to p.stdout.seekable() returns True and the call to seek works as expected most of the time.
If the answer is "no", why does it work most of the time? Also, if seek is not allowed here, shouldn't p.stdout.seekable() return False?
The following program executes without any errors:
import subprocess
import time

p = subprocess.Popen("timeout /t 2", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(type(p.stdout))
assert p.stdout.seekable()
time.sleep(0.5)
p.stdout.seek(0, 2)
byte_count = p.stdout.tell()
p.stdout.seek(0)
data = p.stdout.read(byte_count)
print(data)

Output:
<class '_io.BufferedReader'>
b'\r\nWaiting for 2 seconds, press a key to continue ...'

The target platform is Windows 11, Python v3.11.5.

There is a bug on this here: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/86768
Apparently it is a bug / shortcoming of MSVCRT.

Yes, despite that MSVCRT knows the type of the file descriptor because it calls GetFileType() on its creation, it doesn't check it in lseek() implementation and simply calls SetFilePointer(), which spuriously succeeds for pipes. MSDN says the following[1]:
Calling the SetFilePointer function with a handle to a non-seeking device such as a pipe or a communications device is not supported, even though the SetFilePointer function may not return an error. The behavior of the SetFilePointer function in this case is undefined.
[1] https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setfilepointer

In short:

No, pipes are not seekable
On Windows, seeking is treated as a no-op that does not cause an error
On all other OSs it would cause an error
Because it's undefined behavior, it may change in the future, though I doubt MS would break existing applications


"On Windows, seeking is treated as a no-op that does not cause an error" It's clearly doing an operation of some sort, as tell() reports the new (correct) location which can be used to determine how many bytes are available. It's not silently doing nothing, it's actually behaving as if the pipe is seekable. Agreed on points 3 and 4.

@devtk I don't fully understand that part, either. What happens if you read 2 bytes, then seek, then read again? I would assume that the BufferedReader discards its buffer, thinking it can re-read it after seeking. But in practice it cannot, so you would lose data
